# gmp.h file not found error in Xcode, mac

Tags: c++, c, xcode, macos, gmp

I downloaded `gmp-6.0.0a.tar.xz` file and unzip(tar) in `usr/local` directory. 
As people said , I typed `./configure`, `make`, `make check` and `sudo make install` in the `gmp-6.0.0` directory.
  Installing seemed fine. But when i tried to test like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <gmpxx.h>


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // insert code here...
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

it has error that `gmp.h` file not found. 
I added `-lgmp` to Other Linker Flags but not works.

I do not know how to deal with this kind of problem. Could anyone help?

---

Thank you Dietrich Epp. 
Now I do not have a error of not gmp.h file found but
I do have gmpxx.h file not found. 
I don't know why..

Any suggestion???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ support is *not* enabled by default when configuring GMP. Untar the package, and configure with: `./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-cxx` - this will also install the `gmpxx.h` header, and the `libgmpxx.dylib` and / or `libgmpxx.a` libraries

Not sure if the latest GMP picks up clang for the C++ compiler. You can manually set the environment variables, e.g., `CC=clang` (C99 default), and: `CXX=clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++` (C++11 dialect - also passes C++11 options to the linker). Again, this might be unnecessary.

Your test, since it includes C++, must be built as a C++ application. Also, `libgmpxx.dylib` is itself linked to `libgmp.dylib`, so for a simple C++ test program:

```
$CXX -I/usr/local/include gmptest.cc -o gmptest -L/usr/local/lib -lgmpxx
```

should be sufficient.

It may be necessary to prepend `/usr/local/lib` to the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable, if other system GMP library installations are used first, unless you hardcode the library with the linker `-rpath` option. But that's something to worry about if and when the problem arises.

Comment: it works!! thank you very much. Two answers are very grateful. I do not know which one I should accept.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you should not untar it in `/usr/local`.  Just untar it somewhere in your home directory (it doesn't matter), then `./configure; make; make check; sudo make install`.

Your problem may be caused by the compiler not searching `/usr/local/include`.

1. Check that `/usr/local/include/gmp.h` exists.  If it doesn't exist, GMP is installed incorrectly (or installed in a different location).
2. Add `-I/usr/local/include` to your compiler flags.  In Xcode, this is done by adding `/usr/local/include` to the "additional header search paths" in the project settings (or some setting like that).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So far it works. However because I want to add `#include <gmpxx.h>` it also has the same problem that `gmpxx.h` file not found.